# installing behat on windows 7: not getting the autoexec

Tags: windows, windows-7, behat

I'm trying to install [behat](http://behat.org) on a Windows Virtual Machine, but I'm getting stuck with the windows command prompt. Here is what I did:

1. Installed xampp
2. Installed [Composer for windows](http://diywebdev.com/setting-up-composer-php-dependencies-manager-in-windows/)
3. Donwloaded [behat using the git method](http://docs.behat.org/quick_intro.html#method-3-git) (other methods do not
   work for me) to C:\behat so that
   C:\behat\bin\behat.bat and C:\behat\bin\behat both exist
4. open windowns control panel
5. search for "environment"
6. click "edit the system environment variables"
7. system and security > edit the system environment variables: add the the end of PATH "C:\behat\bin"

At this point I expect to be able to type in behat anywhere on my system using the command prompt as administrator, because the "bin" directory containing "behat.bat" is contained in the PATH, but typing in "behat" gives me "Could not open input file @bin_dir@\behatcd". typeing in behat.bat does not work either

I have never used Windows before so, this is probably obvious but I'm just not getting it.

Any advice greatly appreciated, thanks.

Albert

Comment: I don't think '@bin_dir@` is a recognized Windows shortcut like say `%SystemRoot%`, if you have that input somewhere in the environment variables you should probably remove it, and instead modify the `PATH` so that it contains your `C:\behat\bin` folder.

Comment: step by step guide to install Behat on windows machine. http://openguider.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/how-to-install-behat-on-windows/

Answer (score 4):

try typing

```
php behat
```

windows doesn't know behat is a php file and you need to tell it what to execute it with

Comment: Thanks j0k, I still can't get behat into the path, but "php" is what I needed. Typing in "php C:\behat\bin\behat" works fine now (it is the equivalent of typing "behat" on linux.

Comment: That was the solution in my case on XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the step by step guide to install Behat on windows machine. [openguider](http://openguider.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/how-to-install-behat-on-windows/)